# C# Effective way to manage revision number

Tags: c#

C# 2008 SP1

I am wondering what is the best way to handle revision numbers.

I had always thought there is normally only 3 numbers. (Major, Minor, and Bug fixes).

However, I am left wondering what the build number is and the Revision number.

For example, in the past I have normally used only 3 numbers. I there is some very minor change or a bug fix I would increment the 3rd number (bug fixes).

Because I am new to this. What is normally done in the professional world?

Many thanks for any advice,

In my AssemblyInfo file I have the following:

```
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.2.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]

// 1.0.2 Added feature for detecting if a sound card is installed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your suggestions.

I have decided to use the following.

My project has the following version number: 1.0.2.20.
1.  :Major changes
0.  :Minor changes
2.  :Bug fixes
20  :Subversion revision number

So I have changed the following in my assemblyinfo.c file

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.2.20")]
```

Any suggestions on this idea, I would be happy to hear.

Many thanks,

Comment: Tracking the number of bug fixes will be hard if you've got a number of different programmers working on the same code.

Answer (score 10):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx):

> - Build : A difference in build number represents a recompilation of
>     the same source. This would be
>     appropriate because of processor,
>     platform, or compiler changes.
> - Revision : Assemblies with the same name, major, and minor version numbers
>     but different revisions are intended
>     to be fully interchangeable. This
>     would be appropriate to fix a security
>     hole in a previously released
>     assembly.

Phil Haack has a [nice deconstruction](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Which_Version_of_Version.aspx) of the .NET versioning system, but in practice I don't think his concerns really matter since in my experience the .NET/MS versioning system is only really used by technical for debugging/support/tracking purposes, the public and project management will often be date or made-up-marketing-version-number based.

FWIW every .NET project I've worked on ha been governed by "X.Y.*" i.e. we like to manually control what the major and minors are but let the system control the build and revision.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/

Comment: We used to use a similar approach but found that long term management with this method is actually quite difficult. For one it doesn't work well with Continuous integration and wreaks havoc on incremental builds. Eventually we switched to using the SVN version number as our build number which made more sense from a publishing/bug tracking point of view.

Answer (score 5):

I think Paul Alexander's answer is the correct one but I'd like to add the following remark to your AssemblyInfo file:

If you use `1.0.2.*` remember that the last bit (replaced by the `*`) is a random number So if you build `1.0.2.`*` this evening, and you build it again tomorrow morning, the second version could have a lower version number than the build you did earlier.

Comment: According to MSDN : "The default build number increments daily. The default revision number is random. "

Comment: Well, if it is random you can get the same anomaly: that a later build has a lower version number than the earlier version.

Comment: Just for the record, the revision number is not random (anymore). Now, auto-incremented build and revision represent date and time respectively. Build is number of days passed since 01.01.2000, and revision is number of seconds passed that day divided by two (due to 65535 limitation I believe).

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to consider versioning your assembly and file differently. When you change the assembly version number it's possible, but extremely difficult, for existing code to use it without recompiling. We only change the assembly version when there are breaking changes so we can release minor bug fixes easily.

Read more on our [Assembly Versioning](http://xheo.com/knowledge-base/deploylx/general/assembly-versioning) policy.

Comment: Assemblies are treated as the same in the .net framework (binding), if you don't change the Major and Minor version number

Comment: That's not actually true. When you use strong names the entire version number is considered.

Comment: The link in your answer is now broken. I believe it's now [this one](http://xheo.com/knowledge-base/deploylx/general/assembly-versioning).

Answer (score 2):

We use the Bug-fix number in increments of two. Odd numbers mean released minor bug fixes and even numbers mean working on bug fixes. Apparently this is common in some businesses, i.e., the one I am in.

The idea is to identify accidental releases, and somehow I like the idea. Doing things so that you easily see things that are wrong. This does not say that an odd number necessarily is a non-accidental release, only that it is with a quite high probability.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way round? Because, a .0 in your system means a development version, but a 1.0.0 release is likely a real release, isn't it? :D Apart from that, I like this system. Makes sense. I'm always unsure when to increase the number (because, too early means there is a "wrong" version, and too late means you can't test early with the new version number).